# How to assign a variable pointer to access hardware register on msp430?

Tags: c, embedded, msp430

For context I'm using the `mspgcc` and the `msp430g2553` on the launchpad development board.

I want to create a pointer that can point to various hardware registers.  The standard header provides access to the registers through statements like this:

```
P1DIR &= 0x08;
```

The above is the direction register for port 1 gpio pins.  `P1DIR` is a 8bit hardware register.

My attempts to assign a pointer that can be used to modify this are as follows:

```
volatile unsigned char *reg;
reg = (unsigned char *) &P1DIR;
```

This does not generate any errors or warnings by gcc however it does not work.  When using the gdb to test for values reg contains the value `0xFFFF` instead of `0x0022` (address of `P1DIR`) as stated in the data sheet.

Here are the lines from the header to help with the problem:

```
/* External references resolved by a device-specific linker command file */
#define SFR_8BIT(address)   extern volatile unsigned char address
...
SFR_8BIT(P1DIR);                              /* Port 1 Direction */
```

As far as I could find the linker uses a file called `periph.x` (located at `/usr/local/msp430-uniarch-20110716/msp430/lib/ldscripts/msp430g2553`) which contains the line:

```
__P1DIR = 0x0022;
```

Comment: The compiler probably uses special extension keywords to declare the register variables. You should look in the header files how they are declared. It might simply not be possible to use them as pointers.

Comment: As the variables are declared to be `extern` they are defined somewhere else, possible in a linker script or a system object file you link with.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Note my edits.  I found the linker file.  If this is not possible do you have any better solutions?  Should I just abstain from using the defines and hard code the addresses when doing assignment?

Comment: This is a long shot, but perhaps you can try enclosing the P1DIR like this: reg=(unsigned char *)&(P1DIR);

Comment: I disassembled my code and the problem seems to be that even though I'm using the volatile code word the compiler is optimizing out my variable and using bit set / bit clear operations on the registers.  For that reason gdb is not giving good values for the pointer, however the code does work.  I never set any optimization, this is frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing compiler specific at all required, just standard C...

```
#define WDTCTL     (*((volatile unsigned short *)0x0120))
#define P1DIR (*((volatile unsigned char *)0x0022))
...
    WDTCTL = 0x5A80;
...
    P1DIR |= 0x01;
    P1OUT |= 0x01;
    P1DIR &= ~0x02;
```

Then check your disassembly to make sure it worked.

```
f8b4:   b2 40 80 5a     mov #23168, &0x0120 ;#0x5a80
...
    f8ca:   d2 d3 22 00     bis.b   #1, &0x0022 ;r3 As==01
    f8ce:   d2 d3 21 00     bis.b   #1, &0x0021 ;r3 As==01
    f8d2:   f2 f0 fd ff     and.b   #-3,    &0x0022 ;#0xfffd
```

Comment: The reason I was confused lies in GDB somewhere.  I compiled using the -S flag which outputs an assembly file and discovered that the variable `reg` is being addressed relative to the frame pointer (r4).  However when you used the command `x \x reg` in GDB it printed the value at the frame pointer which happened to be `0xffff` since this is the main function.  The real variable was being stored two bytes down from the frame pointer (which happened to be the same place r1/SP was pointing to).